# What is the runtime for this code

Tags: python, runtime, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, orders

```
def mystery11(n):
  if n < 1: return n
  def mystery12(n):
    i = 1
    while i < n:
      i *= 2
    return i
  return mystery11(n/2) + mystery11(n/2) + mystery12(n-2)
```

I have a question about the code above. I completely understand that without the last recursive call to mystery12, the runtime of the code (mystery11) would be theta(n). But I don't believe that at each level theta(log(n)) work is being done.

At the first level, we do log(n), at the next level, we do 2log(n/2), then 4log(n/4)... but that doesn't look like log(n) at each level (it feels closer to 2log(n) at the second level and 4log(n) at the third level etc.)

I've also tried Wolfram Alpha, and I just get [no solutions exist](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3Df(n%2F2)%2Bf(n%2F2)+log(n),+f(1)%3D1,+f(0)+%3D+0,+f(-1)+%3D+-1).
But works fine without the log(n) term.

So, is this solution correct theta(nlog(n))? And if not, what is the actual solution?

Ps. Apologies if anything in my post is not etiquette, this is my second time posting on Stackoverflow. Post a comment and I will fix it.

Comment: You should paste your code here directly. Not through an image or link.

Comment: Got it! Rewrote the code in the body of the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mystery12` is independent of any external functions / variables, let's look at it first.

After the `j`-th iteration of the while-loop, `i = 2^j`. Therefore the maximum number of loops is given by the equation `2^j >= n`, or `j = ceil(log2(n))` where `ceil` rounds up to the nearest integer.

---

Now for `mystery11`. Each call contains 2 recursive calls to `mystery11` with argument `n / 2`, and a call to `mystery12` with argument `n - 2`. This gives the time complexity recurrence relation (`C` is some positive constant):

[image]

You have already correctly deduced that the recursion depth is `m ~ log n`. The precise value is `m = ceil(log2(n))`. Using the fact that a number rounded up only differs from itself by less than 1, we can eliminate some of the rounding brackets:

[image]

---

Let's examine `B` first. A problem arises - the expression inside the logarithm can be negative. This is mitigated by the fact that the while-loop `mystery12` *never* executes if `n - 2 < 1` - i.e. its complexity can be truncated to `O(1)` in this edge case. Therefore, the sum is *bounded from above* by:

[image]

Where we used a Taylor expansion of `log`. Hence `B` can be ignored in our analysis as it is already overshadowed by the first term.

---

Now to examine `A`. This is a slightly tedious summation which I will use [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+j+*+2%5Ej+from+0+to+n+-+1) to compute:

[image]

> Therefore the overal time complexity of `mystery11` is **`Θ(n)`**, not `Θ(n log n)` as predicted.

---

Why is this? The reason lies in "each recursive call does `log n` work" - `n` here is not the same as the initial value of `n` passed to `mystery11` (the `n` in the *overall* time complexity). At each recursion level `n` decreases exponentially, so:

> We *cannot* naively multiply the amount of work done per call with the number of recursive calls.

This applies to complexity analysis in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I couldn't understand what your question is.

It seems not clear to me.

Whatever it is,

I did the math according to your 'mystery' code.

---

Let's say 'm1' is the mystery11, 'm2' is the mystery12.

Without m2,

time cost would be like this.

```
m1(n)
= 2*m1(n/2)
= 2*( m1(n/4) + m1(n/4) ) = 4*m1(n/4)
= .....
= 2^k * m1( n / 2^k )
```

For the k which makes 2^k n,

2^k = n.

Then time cost for m1(n) is n * m1(1) = n.

---

Time cost of m2 is log(n) obviously.

With m2,

time cost changes like this.

```
m1(n)
= 2*m1(n/2) + log(n)
= 2*( m1(n/4) + m1(n/4) + log(n) ) + log(n) = 4*m1(n/4) + ( log(n) + 2log(n) )
= ....
= 2^k * m1(n/2^k) + ( log(n) + 2log(n) + 4log(n) ... 2^(k-1)*log(n) )
= 2^k * m1(n/2^k) + log(n) * ∑( 2^(k-1) ) ( where k is from 1 to k )
= 2^k * m1(n/2^k) + log(n)/2 * ∑( 2^k )
= 2^k * m1(n/2^k) + log(n)/2 * ( 2^(k+1) - 1 )
= 2^k * m1(n/2^k) + 2^k * log(n) - log(n)/2
```

Just like the previous one,

for the k which makes 2^k n,

```
2^k * m1(n/2^k) + 2^k * log(n) - log(n)/2
= n * m1(1) + n*log(n) - log(n)/2 = n + n*log(n) - log(n)/2
```

I believe you can do the rest from here.

Ps. My apologies if it's not what you asked for.